# Accessing template arguments from specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct A;

template<std::size_t I>
struct A<int, char[I]> {
    using pointer = T*; // does not compile
};

int main() {
    A<int, char[3]> a;    
}
```

Is there any way to access the type `T` (= `int`) from inside the class template specialization `A<int, char[I]>`, without explicitly writing the type that is has in the specialization?

Comment: Do you want this just to save on typing? Or do you need the genericity for some other reason?

Comment: By inheritance and repeating for the base class (but not inside the class :-) ).

Comment: to save typing (the real code is much more complex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
template<class T, class U, class=T, class=U>
struct A;

template<std::size_t I, class T, class U>
struct A<int, char[I], T, U> {
  using pointer = T*;
};
```

works.  If someone actually passes a type for the second `T` and `U` problems develop, but...

Another approach is:

```
template<class T, class U>
struct A;

// get args from an instance!
template<class A>
struct A_Args;
template<class T_, class U_>
struct A_Args<A<T_,U_>> {
  using T = T_; using U = U_;
};
template<class A>
using A_T = typename A_Args<A>::T;
template<class A>
using A_U = typename A_Args<A>::U;

// reflect on our troubles:
template<std::size_t I>
struct A<int, char[I]> {
  using pointer = A_T<A>*;
};
```

where we have a `using` alias that extracts args from a generic `A` which we use within the specialization.

This version can be made generic with an interface like:

```
template<std::size_t I, class Instance>
struct nth_template_arg;
template<std::size_t I, class Instance>
using nth_template_arg_t=typename nth_template_arg<I, Instance>::type;
```

with the note it will only work with templates that only take type arguments.  (implementation left as an exercise.  I'd probably use `tuple_element` for a first pass; using tuples has the downside that they are heavy types, and metaprogramming with heavy types sucks performance and sometimes causes other problems.)

Answer (score -1):

Simply,

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class U>
struct foo;

template<class T, std::size_t Index>
struct foo<T, char[Index]>
{
    using type = T;
};

int
main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<foo<int, char[3]>::type, int>::value, "");
}
```

Comment: The specialization should not be templated for `T`, `T` should always be `int` in this specialization.

Comment: If T is known to you at all times why you need a typedef to refer on?

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
template<typename T, typename U, std::size_t I>
struct A{
    using pointer = T*;
};
```